# How can i convert my string with my common language to English?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I have some Excel data including an Excel column I created programatically in sql table my excel column on the other hand. One of the column's name's is `mydetail`.  When I try to  convert it to uppercase I get `MYDETAİL`. How do I use the ToUpper() method to obtain `MYDETAIL` not `MYDETAİL`?

Comment: This question makes no sense to me at all. Please explain in more detail (and maybe better english?) if possible.

Answer (score 5):

I'm guessing that you are Turkish, or at least using a Turkish computer.

In Turkish the "i" does convert to "İ" in upper case.

You need to use a different culture when doing the conversion by using [`String.ToUpper`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24kc78ka.aspx) method that takes an `CultureInfo` object as an argument. If you use en-US or en-GB you should get what you want.

In fact the example on the page I linked to uses en-US and tr-TR (Turkey-Turkish) on the word "indigo" as an example of the differences.

Comment: @Phsika - Turkish is (as far as I know) the only language that has an upper case I with a dot (İ)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
String result = source.ToUpper(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=VS.71%29.aspx):

> use the InvariantCulture to ensure that the behavior will be consistent regardless of the culture settings of the system

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call `.ToUpper()` with the desired **CultureInfo**. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewdd6aed.aspx) with some examples on how to use .ToUpper(CultureInfo).

---

It is recommended to specify CultureInfo on all String manipulation methods like String.Format(), `<primitive>`.ToString() or for example Convert.Int32(object, CultureInfo).

[FxCop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb429476%28VS.80%29.aspx) does a good job in reminding you on issues with this in your code.